# Notifications wrongly positioned in my KDE+i3wm setup

Tags: kubuntu, kde, notification, i3-wm, debugging

I am observing a weird behavior on my KDE+i3wm setup.

### The issue

The issue is with the positioning of the notifications. Even though I have configured the notifications to appear near the panel. **They appear at the center of the display.**
[Notification Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iZDJ.jpg)

However, I have observed that this issue only happens when I log into the OS for the first time after booting. If I log out, and then log back in, then the behavior is as desired.
[Things on first login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUQi2.jpg)
[Things as expected after login-logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59SUU.jpg)

### What this question asks

Being new to KDE, I am not able to debug this issue, though I have been trying out various things continuously to observe its behaviour, but that doesn't mean I'll be satisfied with a hack just to get things working. *For now, I can easily hack i3wm config to move the notifications to the desired place*, but that's not what I want.
I want to fix this issue properly, that is by understanding the cause. **Please guide me in debugging this issue**. I'll gladly respond with whatever information you'd require for analysing the issue.

### Update

I think I have funneled down the cause of this issue. I think the notifications refer to the window titled "**Desktop - Plasma**" to fetch the position. Since, in my i3 config, I was killing the window, hence the reason for this issue.
If I let the window open, then the notifications appear fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have written in the **Update** not killing the window titled **Desktop - Plasma** in the i3 config fixed this issue.

Comment: Isn't killing the `Desktop - Plasma` window necessary to keep your wallpapers visible?

Comment: It isn't necessarily required to kill it. I just moved it out of my sight using `move scratchpad`.